# How to store and return results from MQTT callback function? PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mqtt

I have installed a `PHP` library for `MQTT` from this [link.](https://github.com/php-mqtt/client)

Now I want to use it within an ajax call performed with `axios` to retrieve data from a broker. So I followed an example and created the controller `MqttController@KreirajMqtt`:

```
public function KreirajMqtt()
{
    $server = 'mqtt3.thingspeak.com';
    $port = 1883;
    $username = 'myUsername';
    $clientId = 'myId';
    $password = 'myPassword';

    $mttq = new MqttClient($server, $port, $clientId);

    $connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings();
    $connectionSettings
        ->setUsername($username)
        ->setPassword($password)
        ->setKeepAliveInterval(15)
        ->setLastWillTopic('channels/myChannel/subscribe')
        ->setLastWillMessage('client disconnect')
        ->setLastWillQualityOfService(0);

    $mttq->connect($connectionSettings, true);

    $mttq->subscribe(
        'channels/myChannel/subscribe',
        function ($topic, $message) {
            echo sprintf("Received message on topic [%s]: %s\n", $topic, $message);
        },
        0
    );
}
```

How can I change this so that it returns the data retrieved via MQTT to my frontend where I want to display it using Vue.js?

Comment: Do you need to receive messages over time, e.g. for a whole hour? Or do you need to retrieve a single message only? And how often are messages published to the topic you subscribe to?

Comment: I do not know. I am really new to this. I have project to subscribe to this channel, and to read it fields, and then to show that readings on my web page. These fields are measurements from different sensors which are in greenhouse so I guess they change maybe hourly.  Site I use is ThingSpeaks and front-back are Vue and Laravel. I have to show current values, and to have option to show values from past hour/week/month, but I have problem with reading anything from MQTT

Comment: I don't know ThingSpeak, but from [their documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readdata.html) I would say you are looking into the wrong direction. I suggest querying the data using their REST API. If you need to use MQTT, you'd have to implement an Artisan command which subscribes to a topic and stores retrieved data in a database. The command should be kept running using supervisord or similar. The controller would then only publish data from the database. To show live data on the website, you'd need websockets on top.

Comment: Well this is how they described MQTT. They do not have a lot of documentation about it, and I have to use it.. Do you have example for that Artisan command, or link to instructions. Also, for websockets too

Comment: MQTT is what the sensor device is using to transmit sensor data to the platform. As far as I see it, you should be able to retrieve this data from the platform using the provided REST API. Since the platform already seems to store and provide historical data, I don't see a need to implement all that in your application (again). Laravel would theoretically provide everything necessary except websocket support, but I don't think that is the right solution to this problem.

Comment: I guess I will then have to ask my professor to use REST instead of this damn MQTT. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238620/discussion-between-raskoljnikovic-and-namoshek).